# On linear homotopy of operators

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $F$ be an isomorphism of euclidian space $E$, with orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\ldots e_n\}$. Let $F'$ be orthogonalised $F$.

Is any operator $F_t$ from linear homotopy of $F$ and $F'$ an isomorphism ($F_t=tF'+(1-t)F$, $t\in [0;1]$)?

**A little explanation on $F':$** let $\{f_1,\ldots f_n\}$ be an image of $\{e_1,\ldots e_n\}$ under $F$, $f_i:=F(e_i)$, we then apply Gram–Schmidt process (without norming), and get $\{f_1',\ldots f_n'\}$. $F'$ is defined as $F'(e_i)=f_i'$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This follows from the fact that Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization changes your basis by an upper-triangular matrix with $1$s on the diagonal: the first basis vector is kept the same, the second has some multiple of the first added to it, the third has some linear combination of the first two added to it, and so on.  This means that $F'=FT$ for some upper-triangular matrix $T$ with $1$s on the diagonal.  It follows that $F_t=F(tI+(1-t)T)$, and $tI+(1-t)T$ is again upper-triangular matrix with $1$s on the diagonal and hence invertible.